# Python 3 multi index data frame visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization, multi-index

I have a dataset with country, date, confirmed, deaths and recovered. 
I have grouped on the base of country and date what i need to do now is plot the Confirmed column  (int) with date and country (multi index).

```
country = data.groupby(['Country','Date'])['Confirmed','Recovered','Deaths'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).sum())
```

[image: country.info()]

When I do

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.FacetGrid(country.reset_index(), row='Date', col='Confirmed')
g.map(sns.distplot, "Country")
```

It doesn't show anything. Keeps computing for good 30-40 minutes using more than 85% of memory.

Comment: *"When I do `...` It keeps on executing."* - What do you mean by this?

Comment: You might also tag this with `seaborn` or otherwise add `import seaborn as sns` to your example

Comment: It just never stops executing. I even let it run for good 30-40 minutes but still nothing shows up.

Comment: did you mean `g=sns.FacetGrid(...); g.map(...)`?